# Why cannot add resources to the folder in VS 2010 Express?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, resources

Hi
In order to be able to work with e.g. picture, I need to click on Resources.resx and Add Existing Item.
Then it will appear under Resources folder. However I could use Context menu on that Resource folder and add existing item as well but then I cannot work with it and it is not displayed when I use the Resources.resx file.
So I always need to click on Resources.rext when I want to add anything? Also in this "view" I cannot use folders so its pretty messy.
Also what is New Folder in Resources dir good for - when I drag files there, there are not accessible anymore..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct; to add something to a ResX file, you need to add it to the ResX file.

Instead of folders, you can use multiple ResX files.

You can also embed images in your assembly (set `Build Action` to `Embedded Resource`) instead of using ResX files; you can then create arbitrary directory trees.
To read embedded resources, call `typeof(MyType).Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(name)` and remember to close the stream in a `using` statement.